# Protecting Jersey web service with SSL

Tags: rest, ssl, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I have pretty simple web-service, which runs on the Embedded Glassfish server:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/id")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class SimpleFacadeBean {

    @GET
    public String sayHello(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

And corresponding class, that set root-element for all web-service calls:

```
@ApplicationPath("root")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

Everything works fine, but I want to protect this GET method through SSL. 
I have read such manuals as: [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/466202/Web-Services/java/SSL-Web-Services-Glassfish), and [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/using-jax-ws-based-web-services-wit.html). I am not interested in configuring Glassfish part of SSL connection (I know how to do it), I just want not to see my GET method in *localhost:8080/root/application.wadl* link (this will mean that my web-service is connected to 8181 secure glassfish port, not to default unsecure 8080 port). 
For this purpose I wrote web.xml descriptor and put it in webapp/WEB-INF directory. The most interesting part of it looks like:

```
<security-constraint>   
    <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>   
    <web-resource-collection>   
        <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>   
        <url-pattern>/root/id</url-pattern>               
        <http-method>GET</http-method>   
    </web-resource-collection>             
    <user-data-constraint>   
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>   
    </user-data-constraint>   
</security-constraint>
```

But after executing I saw (in *application.wadl*) again my web-service URL connected to unsecured port (8080 instead of 8181). I have tried a lot of other ways, trying to make my code work correctly. I was not successful at all.
I package this web-services into .war. After that this .war goes to .ear. Any ideas why I am not successful in NOT seeing my "secure" web-service in *application.wadl*?

Comment: how do you generate `application.wadl`? with which tool?

Comment: Have you tried, just for the sake of test broader pattern, like /root/id/* pattern or /* and see what would happen.